# What is the expression language being used in log4.xml for accessing java system properties?

Tags: java, xml, log4j, expression

I am using expressions in my log4j.xml for setting severity levels, however I would like to know what else can I do with those expressions. For example adding some logic or more complex resolution, I cannot find what is the expression language supported by log4j.xml file.

For example I want to set a property which name is dynamic depending on the context of the application being configured, that way I can use the java system properties to communicate that configuration to the log4j configuration for multiple versions of the same application:

```
Application version 1 --> app1.mypackage.severity
Application version 2 --> app2.mypackage.severity
```

appX is resolved by the application container at the moment of initialization, so my problem can be reduced to knowing how to concatenate the value of two expressions but I cannot find what is the expression language being used by log4j.

I want something like this:

```
...
<logger name="mypackage" additivity="false">
    <level value="${$appVersion+$mypackage.severity}" />
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFile" />
</logger>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

This page describes how to use variables in log4j configuration files.

The basic format is same for most apache tools, like maven and ant.

```
${name}
```

where `name` is defined as a property somewhere (environment variables, system properties, local properties, etc). Check the link to see various ways to set the properties.

To embed variables in variables, you can use local property definitions within the configuration xml, eg:

```
<Properties>
  <Property name="loggerlevel">${appVersion}${mypackage:severity}</Property>
</Properties>
...
<logger name="mypackage" additivity="false">
  <level value="${loggerlevel}" />
  <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFile" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Maybe that is a feature only available in log4j 2, when I tried it on log4j 1.2.17 it threw some warnings like: WARN Element type "Properties" must be declared.